# 2D Spatial Fourier Tranform on a pressure field

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-domain, acoustics, spatial

I'm doing some research on Fourier Near-field Acoustic Holography (NAH). The basic theory behind Fouerir NAH is that you take a sound pressure field measurement in a 2d plane p(x,y), 2d spatial Fourtier transform the sound pressure field into the wavenumber domain where it's spatial variation of phase is known, multiply by a propagator and inverse transform back to pressure at the propagated plane.

I'm getting confused with the fact that pressure is usually a time varying signal i.e. p(t) = ...
Fourier transforming pressure would give us the temporal frequency i.e. P(ω). I don't understand how you can measure pressure in the space domain (x,y) and then get to the wavenumber domain with no time involved. Do you need to apply one Fourier Transform to get to the frequency domain, and then another FT to get to the wavenumber domain?

Comment: Hello TJS and welcome to Physics SE. I have already provided a (possible) answer to your question but as stated in some comments, it may not be relevant. Could you please clarify whether it is a better understanding of the spatial Fourier Transform, a way to implement the spatial Fourier Transform, its connection with the temporal variable or something else that you seek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Time domain representation

As Max have presented in their answer, acoustic pressure variations in two dimensions, that you are interested in, is given as a function of time $t$ and spatial (Cartesian in our case) coordinates $x$ and $y$, denoted by $p \left( x, y, t \right)$.

Now, consider taking a snapshot of the function at some arbitrary time $t_{1}$. You can visualise that as a two-dimensional scalar field $p \left( x, y, t_1 \right)$. For a simple monochromatic plane acoustic wave of (temporal) frequency 100 Hz, with propagation direction $60^{o}$ (measuring counterclockwise from the x-axis) it will be as the image shown below.

[image: Monochromatic plane wave with f = 100 Hz traveling in the direction of 60 degrees (counterclockwise from the x axis)]

In the same way, you could possibly add another monochromatic component to this signal in the same direction. For an additional component of 180 Hz this would look like the next image.

[image: Superposition of two monochromatic plane waves with f1 = 100 Hz and f2 = 180 Hz, traveling in the direction of 60 degrees (counterclockwise from the x axis)]

Now, to make it more generic you could make the second component travel in a different direction. The next images show an example of the second component (still 180 Hz temporal frequency) travel in a direction of $110^{0}$. The first image shows the two components (it is compressed in the y direction due to plotting issues, apologies) and the second their superposition.

[image: Monochromatic plane waves with f = 100 Hz and f2 = 180 Hz traveling in the directions of 60 and 110 degrees (counterclockwise from the x axis) respectively]

[image: Superposition of two monochromatic plane waves with f = 100 Hz and f2 = 180 Hz traveling in the directions of 60 and 110 degrees (counterclockwise from the x axis) respectively]

You could possibly imagine what the case would be if you were to add more and more frequency components with various directions of propagation.

Now, if you take a closer look at all the images you'll see that there's some distinct repetition patterns both in the $x$ and $y$ axes. These repetition patterns constitute the basis of the spatial frequencies. The spatial frequency, "encoded" in the wavenumber shows how many repetitions you get in a spatial dimension per distance measure. In two dimensions the wavenumber can be "split" into two components (in the 2D case and three for the 3D case), one for each axis. For linear acoustic waves (and I believe this is the general case for all linear waves) the equation $k^{2} = k_{x}^{2} + k_{y}^{2}$ must hold. This means that you can calculate the plane wave as the superposition of two plane waves, one traveling in the x-axis direction and the other in the y-axis direction.

Next, think of the two waves separately. If you were to look at them in a single dimension (each one in its own axis that is) you would see the following

[image: X and Y sinusoidal components of two plane waves of f1 = 100 Hz and f2 = 180 Hz, traveling in direction of 60 and 110 degrees (counterclockwise from the x axis)]

Of course, if you change the $y$ dimension offset for the $x$ component and similarly the $x$ offset for the $y$ component you'll see a phase shift.

### Frequency domain representation

From a purely mathematical perspective you can indeed Fourier transform those components and find the frequencies they represent. These are the spatial frequencies of the pressure waves. As you may understand, for time invariant signals, a change in the time variable will only introduce a phase shift to the (spatial) frequency components.

Thus, the respective two-dimensional Fourier transforms of the signals will show the frequencies of each dimension (for $t = constant$). The 2D Fourier transform of a monochromatic plane wave of frequency 100 Hz traveling in the direction of the x axis is

[image: 2D Fourier Transform of monochromatic plane wave of frequency f = 100 Hz traveling in the direction of 0 degrees (measured counterclockwise from the x axis)]

Note that the components are drawn as squares. Since this is a Discrete Fourier Transform, these represent frequency bins.

Some things to note here:

1. In order to make the frequency components more visible I had to zoom-in on the centre of the transformed domain.
2. You can see that this plane wave has frequency components only on the horizontal axis (apologies for the axes not being visible here).
3. The "usual" negative components can be seen as the left side frequency component of the decomposition like in the temporal case.
4. You can spot energy in neighboring bins and this is again due to the (spatial) window. Effectively, in order to eliminate them completely your (spatial) domain must go to infinity or your spatial frequency has to be an integer multiple of the window length (spatial domain). This is the case in temporal domain too.
5. The visualisation is for the amplitude of the frequency components ($\sqrt{z \cdot z^{*}}$ where, $z$ is a complex number representing the Fourier coefficient for each frequency bin).

Now, we can visualise the Fourier transform of the first plane wave we've shown, with (temporal) frequency 100 Hz traveling in the direction of $60^{o}$. This would look like (the same zooming has been done here too)

[image: 2D Fourier Transform of monochromatic plane wave of frequency f = 100 Hz traveling in the direction of 60 degrees (measured counterclockwise from the x axis)]

In this figure you can better see the leakage effect due to the fact that the spatial frequencies of the two wavenumbers $k_{x}$ and $k_{y}$ are not representing frequencies that are an integer multiple of the respective dimensions. Additionally, you can see that now you have a frequency component on the plain whose location does not coincide with any of the axis (but it does coincide with the propagation direction of the wave). Its x coordinate corresponds to the (spatial) frequency of the $k_{x}$ wavenumber and its y coordinate to the (spatial) frequency of the $k_{y}$ wavenumber.

Similarly, you can see the spectrums of the two other cases ($f_{1}$ = 100 Hz, $f_{2}$ = 180 Hz and angles $60^{o}$ for both waves in the first case and $60^{o}$ and $110^{o}$ in the second case) in the next two figures.

[image: 2D Fourier Transform of two monochromatic plane waves of frequency f1 = 100 Hz and f2 = 180 Hz, traveling in the direction of 60 degrees (measured counterclockwise from the x axis)]

[image: 2D Fourier Transform of two monochromatic plane waves of frequency f1 = 100 Hz and f2 = 180 Hz, traveling in the directions of 60 and 110 degrees (measured counterclockwise from the x axis)]

In this way, you can analyse/decompose each two-dimensional plane wave into the superposition of two one-dimensional plane waves and by Fourier transforming their temporal snapshots you can get the spatial frequency components. If you place the spatial components for each temporal frequency on a two-dimensional grid you end up with the two-dimensional Fourier transform. Of course, the transform performs this exact process in a more concise way but the aforementioned procedure can work to provide intuition on the interpretation of the results.

Additionally, the Fourier transform calculates the phase angle for each point in space, which we haven't shown here. Nevertheless I believe it is quite straight forward to do it. You just calculate the two one-dimensional wave components for each point in space (for each propagating wave) and you use the phase of the component on this position's offset like we did with the amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* "time involved", as you put it. The measurement of the pressure field is taken over a span of time. Pressure as in sound pressure is an alternating quantity. The human ear is sensible to alternation of air pressure, not to pressure itself.

The measurement gathers pressure as a function of time *and* two-dimensional space.

$$p(t,x,y)$$

This is transformed not with a spatial fourier transform, but with an "ordinary" one along the time dimension to yield a complex function of frequency *and* space.

$$\mathcal{F}\{ p(t,x,y)\}=P(\omega,x,y)$$

So, only the time component is transformed to frequency, the time information is still there and still will be there after the inverse transformation.

Comment: I believe the OP wants to understand the 2D (in his case) spatial Fourier Transform and not the Fourier Transform of the temporal variable. Although your answer is correct, I believe it does not touch upon the posted question. You explain the transform of the temporal variable (in a correct way) but as I said, I think, the question is about the transform of the spatial variables.

Comment: But the spatial FT has nothing to do with the method  the OP mentioned, the NAH. Your answer ist great for understanding spatial FT, but it does not answer OP's question.

Comment: Then, probably I have misunderstood the question. Thanks for the tip. I'll have a better look at the question and edit (or delete) my answer accordingly.